# Image recognition using Tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm a complete beginner in ML and I'm trying to do image recognition with my mobile camera and a pre-trained model using Tensorflow.js. I've used the [pacman](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/webcam-transfer-learning.html) example in the Tensorflow.js website and modified it.

Here is some of the relevant code :

```
async loadModel() {
  console.log('Loading model...');
  const startTime = performance.now();
  this.model = await loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
  const totalTime = Math.floor(performance.now() - startTime);
  console.log(`Model loaded and initialized in ${totalTime}ms...`);
  this.setup(); // Opens the camera and pass the video stream source to the video element
}
```

This will load the model which I've converted using [tensorflowjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter). After loading the model, I'm opening the camera using `navigator.getUserMedia` and assigning the stream source to the HTML video element I've created in the HTML. Now. After the camera is open , I'm calling the below method for prediction :

```
  async predict() {
    while (this.isPredicting) {
      console.log("predicting . . . . . . . . ");
      const predictionData = tf.tidy(() => {
        // Capture the frame from the webcam.
        const img = this.capture();
        const predictions = this.model.predict(img);

        // Returns the index with the maximum probability. This number corresponds
        // to the class the model thinks is the most probable given the input.
        return predictions;
      });

      const classId = (await predictionData.data());
      console.log(classId);
      predictionData.dispose();
      await tf.nextFrame();
    }
}
```

The `console.log(classId)` is logging below object irrespective of the position of the camera.

```
Float32Array(2) [0.0467529296875, 0.953125]
```

Can anyone help me understand the mistake here please ?

Comment: the values never change? you have 2 classes?

Comment: Your model obviously has an output with two values.

Comment: @f4. I mean, I am expecting the return values to change as I move the camera.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Maybe, but those 2 values should change right ? as I move the camera based on the image ?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please ?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @Supradeep, Sorry for seeing this thread so late. I guess that the issue is related to how your tensor that is passed to the model is generated. Maybe `this.capture()` is returning the same tensor irrespectively of the image. Could you please show the code of `this.capture` ?